# Unit Tests/TDD options that can be used for Delphi and FreePascal

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, tdd, freepascal

I know of the existence of DUnit for Delphi win32.

What I'm after is a library that works both on Delphi AND FreePascal.

If that is not possible at all, I would really appreciate a list of all the options for one(Delphi) AND the other(FreePascal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [FPCUnit](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fpcunit.pdf) an implementation to xUnit for freePascal, i'm not sure if it's compatible with DUnit, but I read at FPC fourms, they are doing improvement to make it compatible with DUnit.

Comment: Your link has an extra period at the end.

Answer (score 1):

utex on tigris.org. The Delphi Unit Test Expert is a AddIn Delphi Expert to create ant develop Test Application for Delphi Units. (sorry as an new user I cannot put directly the link to the project)